# Dropdownlist Datasource by LINQ Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I don't have any clue why ddlCity is not populated when the value of ddlMedicalName is changed. I am just trying to build the function "ddlMedicalName_SelectedIndexChanged" so that if someone choose any MedicalName from the dropdownlist ddlMedicalName, another dropdownlist "ddlCity" datasource should be populated according to the selectedvalue of ddlMedicalName.

Code behind:

```
  protected void ddlMedicalName_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string entityString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["medicaldb2Entities"].ConnectionString;
        //EntityDataSource eds = new EntityDataSource();
        using (Entity.medicaldbEntities context = new Entity.medicaldbEntities())
        {
            string selected = ddlMedicalName.SelectedItem.Value;
            int slct = Convert.ToInt32(selected);

            var orders = from order in context.Cities
                         where order.CityID == slct
                         select new { order.CityID, order.CityName };

            var lstSrc = orders.ToList();

            ddlCity.DataSource = lstSrc;
            ddlCity.DataTextField = "CityName";
            ddlCity.DataValueField = "CityID";

            ddlCity.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

ASPX:

```
<tr id="SearchDropDown">

 <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=medicaldbEntities"  
    DefaultContainerName="medicaldbEntities" EnableFlattening="False" 
    EntitySetName="Medicals" Select="it.[medicalName],it.[CityFK]">
 </asp:EntityDataSource>

<td>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMedicalName" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false"
OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMedicalName_OnSelectedIndexChanged"
    DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1" DataTextField="MedicalName"
    DataValueField="CityFK">
</asp:DropDownList>
</td>
<td>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRegion" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlRegion_SelectedIndexChanged"
    DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1" DataTextField="MedicalName" 
    DataValueField="MedicalName">
</asp:DropDownList>
</td>
<td>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false"
OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCity_SelectedIndexChanged"
     DataTextField="CityID" 
    DataValueField="CityID">
</asp:DropDownList>
</td>
<td>
<asp:Button ID="SearchButton" runat="server" Text="Suche" onclick="SearchButton_Click" />
</td>
</tr>
```

And thats the error I get:

[image]

If I change it to:

```
List<string> lstSrc = orders.ToList();
```

It doesn't throw any error but it doesn't work either (ddlCity is not populated).

Comment: Have you made sure the ddlMedicalName_SelectedIndexChanged -method gets called? Also regarding the error, you should change your select-clause to only include the order (the complete objects), because currently you're selecting a singular property (which happens to be a string) and as such can't save the results in a List of Strings.

Comment: yes, it is not called for sure, I have corrected selectedindexchanged to OnSelectedIndexChanged too but no way

Comment: @bobblez I have also updated the code as you suggested, I have updated the question, I am selecting CityName and CityID

Answer (score 3):

You prepare `query` but never actually use it.

```
var orders = from order in context.Cities
             where order.CityID == slct
             select order.CityName;

List<Entity.City> lstSrc = orders.ToList();
```

**Edit**

Another thing is, you have to take more than just `CityName` from your query:

```
var orders = from order in context.Cities
             where order.CityID == slct
             select new { order.CityID, order.CityName };
```

It will return anonymous type with two properties: `CityID` and `CityName`. But because it's anonymous type, you have to use `var` when declaring your `List<T>` variable:

```
var lstSrc = orders.ToList();
```

or assign it directly to `DataSource` property:

```
ddlCity.DataSource = orders.ToList();
```

Comment: thanks for reply, you are right but it still does not work. I have edited the question. Could you please take a look at it?

Comment: I have tried it but no chance, ddlCity is not updated. It is empty

Comment: Do you have any results in `lstSrc` when try to debug the application?

Comment: I guess the function "ddlMedicalName_SelectedIndexChanged" is not called, I have set a breakpoint and I have changed the value of ddlMedicalName, nothing happened. And lstSrc seeems uninitialized

Comment: Casing on your `onselectedindexchanged` attribute declaration is incorrect. Has to be `OnSelectedIndexChanged`.

Comment: So strange, I have corrected it but still not working. By the way ddlMedicalName_OnSelectedIndexChanged function stands just under the Page_Load(). I guess it is the right place though

Answer (score 1):

```
string selected = ddlMedicalName.SelectedItem.Value;
            int slct = Convert.ToInt32(selected);

            var orders = from order in context.Cities
                         where order.CityID == slct
                         select order.CityName;

            ddlCity.DataSource = orders.ToList();
            ddlCity.DataTextField = "CityName";
            ddlCity.DataValueField = "CityID";
            ddlCity.DataBind();
```

Check Autopostback="true"

```
<asp:Dropdownlist id="ddlMedicalName" runat="Server" Autopostback="true" ></Dropdownlist>
```

Comment: unfortunately it still doesn't work. Maybe there is a misconfiguration by aspx side

Comment: check autopostback=true in ddlmedicalname

Comment: yes now ddlMedicalName_OnSelectedIndexChanged function is called but I guess because of autopostback whenever I select a dropdown value, it is posted to server and all dropdown values are set to default values. I am trying to solve that issue right now

Answer (score 0):

My problem was pretty specific; at the main form tag of the master.site there was a warning. End tag of the form was already there but because of some not allowed controls or tags, it was not detected and didn't rendered and that caused the reason of that strange dropdownlist problem. Then I have edited my html and main form tag and got rid of that "Form1 has no end tag" warning and everything was ok again.